# Regex when set up in custom setting not working giving error

Tags: apex, customsetting, developer

I have set up a regex to match couple of strings. When I use this regex in Apex class directly as string, it works correctly. However when i use the same regex from a custom Text field in Custom Settings it gives below error

> System.StringException: Invalid regex: Illegal character range near
>   index 8 [\d\s-#+@]{7,}

Tried to find a way, however all in vain.

Regex I am using is `[\\d\\s-#+@]{7,}`

Can anybody assist here in resolving this.

Regards
Nitesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're writing Apex Code, the compiler interprets `\` as an escape meant for the source code. The Pattern class interprets `\` as an escape character as well. Therefore, when you use `[\\d\\s-#+@]{7,}`, that means that you're actually passing in literal `\` characters. It becomes interpreted as:

```
[ \ d \ s-# + @ ]{7,}
| 2 3 2  4  5 6 | 7
\-------1-------/

1: Match any character in this set
2: Match a literal "\"
3: Match a literal "d"
4: Match the range "s" through "#"
5: Match a literal "+"
6: Match a literal "@"
7: Match at least 7 times consecutively
```

The problem here is #4: "s" comes after "#", so the compiler won't allow it. It would allow "#" through "s", but this is not your intent.

When you're using data from a string (a label, custom setting, user input, etc), you do *not* escape the `\`, because you're not compiling Apex Code. The regex, as you've written it, would look like the following source code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('[\\\\d\\\\s-#+@]{7,}');
```

To fix this, remove the escape characters that you used to get them in the source code.

The custom setting's value should be:

```
[\d\s-#+@]{7,}
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox! This worked. If you do not mind can i ask you one more question. I tried to we negate in Apex, but that too was not working for me.  Is there any specific things that works differently for negate regex in Apex. Suppose I want to exempt strings starting with + , 0, # and contains @.

Comment: @Nitesh Assuming truth allows the code to continue, you could use OR (`|`): `^([+0#].*@.*)|([\d\s-#+@]{7,})$` (note: did not test this, so you might want to play with it a bit). You might want to read the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class from Java for more explanation.